# Conditionally join a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to conditionally join a query to itself.

The query:

```
SELECT Part, MtlPart, Qty
FROM Mtl
```

The result:

```
Part       MtlPart       Qty
   1          100         1
   1          101         2
   1          102         2
   2          200         1
   2          201         1
 100          120         1
 100          121         1
 100          122         1
 120          A20         1
 120          A21         1
```

MtlParts are also Parts. What I am looking to do is join this query to itself so that I get a list of connecting parts.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT Part, MtlPart, Qty
   FROM Mtl) AS A
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Part, MtlPart, Qty
   FROM Mtl) AS B
ON a.MtlPartNum = b.PartNum
WHERE Part = 1
```

Would return something like:

```
   a.Part      a.MtlPart     a.Qty      b.Part      b.MtlPart    b.Qty
       1          100         1            100         120          1
       1          100         1            100         121          1
       1          100         1            100         122          1
       1          101         1           NULL        NULL        NULL
       1          102         1           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I want to Join this query to itself until the joined query returns only nulls. In this example, Part 1 would return data up until it reached MtlParts A20 and A21 because they are not listed as parts.

I am honestly not sure of the best way to do this. Any help or advice is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What you are describing is not something you should pursue. Having a dynamic amount of columns like that is going to cause you problems as you will end up trying to call columns that don't exist. I would say you should decide to either 1) Only go to X nested levels OR 2) Only identify when a part has a sub part and handle finding the sub part in the list via some code behind filter for the data set.

Comment: @KHeaney option 1 is what I am trying to achieve, but I am struggling with a way to write the loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to go to a limited number of nested levels then you should simply rejoin the table on itself multiple times, for each level, and then select from the sub table. That should look like this based on your example:

```
SELECT A.Part     As APart,
       A.MtlPart  As AMtlPart,
       A.Qty      As AQty,
       B.Part     As BPart,
       B.MtlPart  As BMtlPart,
       B.Qty      As BQty,
       C.Part     As CPart,
       C.MtlPart  As CMtlPart,
       C.Qty      As CQty,
FROM Mtl AS A
    Left Outer JOIN Mtl AS B
        ON A.MtlPartNum = B.Part
    Left Outer JOIN Mtl AS C
        ON B.MtlPartNum = C.Part
WHERE A.Part = 1
```

This would produce the result set

```
APart     AMtlPart   AQty    BPart     BMtlPart   BQty    CPart   CMtlPart   CQty
1         100        1       100       120        1       120     A20        1
1         100        1       100       120        1       120     A21        1
1         100        1       100       121        1       Null    Null       Null
1         100        1       100       122        1       Null    Null       Null
1         101        1       Null      Null       Null    Null    Null       Null
1         102        1       Null      Null       Null    Null    Null       Null
```

By adding more `Joins` you can increase how deep you look. As I mentioned in my comment though, you should not do this dynamically. This would mean that you are limited to how many joins you choose to write so this method would work best if you know how many levels you wanted to look into a part's sub part.

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of necessary nested levels will vary. This is similar to my current code, and works correctly, but I was looking for a way to have it loop. I wasn't sure if that was possible or not. Thank you for the help, and please let me know if you happen to find a way to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks like a reasonable approach, although you seem to want an outer join rather than an inner join.  I would eliminate the subqueries and add aliases:

```
SELECT a.Part, a.MtlPart, a.Qty, b.Part, b.MtlPart, b.Qty
FROM Mtl A LEFT JOIN
     Mtl B
     ON a.MtlPartNum = b.PartNum
WHERE A.Part = 1;
```